# Bluetooth headset with pro-like mic

Tags: audio, bluetooth, headset, microphones, audio-recording

I am looking for some great quality sound headset as well as microphone level close to pro/studio level.

I really enjoy the sound quality and bass line on my **Marshall Major III Bluetooth** headset as well as their long battery life

[image]

however the *mic is absolutely terrible there*, it is so sensitive that sometimes it is not even possible to have a talk or a meeting if there is any slight background noise around.
For example, I had a call while the kids were playing on the garden about 15 meter (50 feet) from me and my friend could not hear me because kids were screaming so loud for her, however for me it was just a slight background noise.

**So is there any Bluetooth headset with similar or better sound quality as well as close to professional level microphone with a short range (just enough for speaking) in it?**

Is there any options that users *can connect external hardware microphone* to the headset?
I don't know is such ones exist though.

Other features like noise reduction, extended BT range, long battery life, comfort controls and so on are welcome.

My budget is **up to $500**.

If you guys can suggest me something really worthy from your own experience I will highly appreciate it! But good mic is the most important for me.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Sensitivity has nothing to do with the amount of background noise picked up. The background is still the same relative level to your voice, no matter how sensitive. Polar pattern is the only differentiator, but I can't imagine any headset mic being other than a cardioid [their site gives no spec I can find].

The only way to reduce background noise [other than move away from it] is to use a noise-cancelling system, using bone conduction [Plantronics, Jawbone] or multiple mics [iPhone etc].